# pattern matching

Tags: shell, pattern-matching

Consider the following rules:

register *

delete *

suppose now if I send a message to the application (via mobile using SMS) that will match the rules

- register Leon Eric

now we have two parameter Leon and Eric and the application
 will assign %P1% for Leon and %P2% for Eric , for further use.

it can be more parameters every parameters have its variable %P1% %P2% %P3% .... %Pn%

the application will reply a custom message that can be changed by the user :

Thank you %P1% %P2%  for your register.

since %P1% is Leon and %P2% is Eric

the message will be "Thank you Leon Eric for your register."

my questions :

What is the best technique I should use with this situation is it regular expression?

I tried to use the regular expression to extract the parameters  but how to group every
 parameter  with name %P1% %P2% ….%Pn% for further use.

register.*? (.+).*?

What is the best technique I should use to replace the message that have an argument with

the parameter that the regular expression assign ?

For example:

Thank you %P1% %P2%  for your register.

"Thank you Leon Eric for your register."

thank you very much

Comment: lol, I can't even read this question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any regex here, just use `%*` to list all parameters:

```
Thank you %*% for your register.
```